# ReleaseHandleFailed with SQLite + Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm receiving an error message in VS2010 after I execute the following code to get values from a SQLite database via an automatically generated ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

```
using (Data.DbEntities ent = new Data.DbEntities())
{
  var r = from tt in ent.Template_DB select tt;
  r.First();//Required to cause error
}
```

The SQLite database table being accessed is called 'Template' (which was renamed to Template_DB for the model) with a few columns holding strings, longs and bits. All queries I've tried return exactly what's expected.

The message I receive is:

> ReleaseHandleFailed was detected
>
> A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type
>   'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeCapiHashHandle' failed to properly
>   release the handle with value 0x0D0DDCF0. This usually indicates that
>   the handle was released incorrectly via another means (such as
>   extracting the handle using DangerousGetHandle and closing it directly
>   or building another SafeHandle around it.)

This message comes up perhaps 60% of the time, up to 8 seconds after the code has completed. As far as I'm aware, the database is not encrypted and has no password. Until recently, I've been using similar MS-SQL databases with Entity Framework models and never seen an error like this.

Help!

EDIT:
I downloaded/installed "sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.81.0.exe" to install SQLite, from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). This included the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.81.0 (3.7.12.1) package (*not* 3.7.13 as stated in the comment below)

Comment: what version of system.data.sqlite are you using?

Comment: 3.7.13 x86... though the DLL says 1.0.81.0 (??). Should've mentioned it, sorry!

Comment: did you download it from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki?

Comment: ah yep (so the 1.0.81.0 makes sense now). I downloaded the first one below the heading "Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)"